# помогите инициализировать экземпляр класса . extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

В коде я удалил все объявленные переменные и объекты, чтобы не захламлять. 
При нажатии на кнопку выкл питание вызывается super.Pause() и но не вызывается surfaceDestroyed. Я решил попробовать переопределить метод onPause() и вызвать через него destroy(). Для этого я в классе Menu должен инициализировать экземпляр объекта класса MainGamePanel. и вызвать mMainGamePanel.gestroy() . Если не инициализирую, появится ошибка Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void example.igeniy.MainGamePanel.destroy()' on a null object reference

Помогите инициализировать и объяснить почему именно так .Спасибо. Так же буду рад, если подскажите почему кнопка выкл питания не вызывает метод surfaceDestroyed.

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setFocusable(true);

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Log.d(TAG,"surfaceChanged");
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG,"surfaceCreated");
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG,"surfaceDestroyed");
    destroy();
}

public  synchronized void destroy(){
    if(thread == null){
        return;
    }
    boolean retry = true;
    thread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry){
        try{
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ignored){
        }
    }
    thread = null;
}
```

И другой класс:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {


 MainGamePanel mMainGamePanel = new MainGamePanel(просит ввести сюда Contex contect); //если дословно ввести Contex contex , то context горит красным (пишу это во избежание глупых советов) 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));

}





@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMainGamePanel.destroy();   // вот что надо  вызвать
    pause = false;
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
}
}
```

Comment: Вы не сможете иницилиализировать View в поле класса активности,  на этом этапе еще не существует контекста

Comment: Почему вы не можете сделать это стандартным способом?

Comment: Вы спрашиваете почему метод `surfaceDestroyed` не вызывается автоматически?

Comment: Не понимаю о каком стандартном способе  вы. Да,  метод surfaceDestroyed  не вызывается автоматически,  если я выкл. экран кнопкой питания . В итоге поток продолжает работать с выключенным экраном. А вот есть кнопкой домой свернуть ,то всё вызывается верно на эмуляторах,  а если пробую на телефоне не помню, что именно, вызовы не верные .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не сможете иницилиализировать View в поле класса активности, на этом этапе еще не существует контекста

Что мешает сделать обыкновенно?

Layout файл (main.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.your.package.MainGamePanel
        android:id="@+id/main_game_panel"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Код активности:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

private MainGamePanel mMainGamePanel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mMainGamePanel = findViewById(R.id.main_game_panel);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMainGamePanel.destroy();   // вот что надо  вызвать
    pause = false;
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
}
```

}

Или в вашем случае:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

private MainGamePanel mMainGamePanel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     mMainGamePanel = new MainGamePanel(this);
    setContentView(mMainGamePanel);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMainGamePanel.destroy();   // вот что надо  вызвать
    pause = false;
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
}
}
```

Comment: В чем отличие этогоsetContentView(new MainGamePanel(this)); от этого mMainGamePanel = new MainGamePanel(this);
    setContentView(mMainGamePanel);  ? Если ни в чем,  то в результате я получу ошибкуMainGamePanel.destroy()' on a null object reference     . Но кажется отличие есть.. В этом случае мы знаем как называется созданный нами экземпляр или как правильнее сказать что мы имеем в этом случае?  Вечером буду дома и попробую

Comment: Интересно было бы узнать в каких случаяхsurfaceDestroyed вызывается, как вы говорите, автоматически. На каких то телефонах он вызывается на каких то нет при одних и тех же операциях.  И вообще не могу понять почему кнопка Назад вызывает метод super.destroy() и всё приложение убито..

Comment: @Turalllb, разница в том, что в первом случае у вас в поле  ссылка будет null, а во втором будет ссылка на объект и ошибки не будет, если непонятно почему читайте основы Android, в частности жизненный цикл активности, заодно и найдете ответ на второй вопрос

Comment: теперь destroy включается сразу после onPause. а раньше при сворачивании после onStop . т.е. игровая ситуация после сворачивая через доли сек останавливалась, если это быстрая игра то она значительно продвинется за это время. а теперь сразу же останавливается, но после onStop вызывается и автоматический метод , но это не критично. Теперь выключение экрана вызывает принудительно метод дестрой, но при включении экрана surfaceCreated не вызывается , так же как и дестрой не вызывался. можно и его принудительно вызывать.Но в случай простого сворачивания он станет вызываться дважды.думаю это эксешен

Comment: не подумал...  surfaceCreated создать не получается , метод mMainGamePanel.Created(сюда надо написать что то); а писать туда нечего потому что от extends AppCompatActivity , а не extends SurfaceView.   и как быть  ? как же запустить поток снова когда экран включается?

Comment: @Turalllb Возможно вам придется обработать все эти случаи вручную ставить флаг isCreatedCall, isDestroyCall, если они не вызвались или наоборот вызвались

Comment: я так и сделал, но приложение стало сразу же зависать. ну как вы думаете каким образом я могу написать метод для surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)  , у меня не получилось потому что я не могу с класса menu передать holder.  создал просто Created() но это привело к неработоспособности программы на телефоне и с ошибкой работало на эмуляторе